# When receiving chinese string, I only get unusable characters

Tags: .net, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I am using an textreader from the internet to read Chinese text, but I'm receiving incorrect letters.

For example, I get back `æ‚¨å¥½ ï¼` instead of `轉注字`. Also, if I parse German strings, I receive `Sie kÃ¶nnen` instead of `Sie können`.

This is the original string from website:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Sie kÃ¶nnen einige Blumen auswÃ¤hlen</string>
```

It is UTF-8 encoded. How do I resolve this encoding issue?

Regards

Comment: This looks like some UTF-8 encoded byte stream was decoded using a 8-bit encoding (probably one of the ISO-8859-* family or of its Windows-* counterparts). I don't know enough about .NET to tell you the correct way, however.

Comment: damn stackoverflow restriction that I am not allowed to answer with fully comments!!!

Comment: Thanks for ideas. The problem was the Webbrowser uses

> iso-8859-1

to decode stuff as standard. I needed to use UTF-8 instead but did not exactly know. I thought it was reversed. The solution is, to just set the browsers encoding before downloading the string (no binary download needed).

Comment: damn stackoverlow restriction that I can not format because I need to wait for 8 hours to answer the question. How should others know that I already found a good answer?

Comment: ...
 

   ' Dim U As Uri = CreateUri(item.German)
                        Me.Web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 
    ' System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) 'System.Text.Encoding.ASCII ' System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
    
                        Me.Web.DownloadStringAsync(U)
'
Result is:

>     Ich pflücke glücklich blümchen

which is correct!

Comment: @goldengel: there's no need to curse, you can edit your question to add information on how you solved it, if you wish.

Comment: Hi Joachim. Has nothing to do with you. But it is NO QUESTION I need to edit. Just found the answer because I searched for ISO-8859 in the internet because of your post. It helped me in this case to find a good keyword to look for. But I would not like to comment this thread because here is no formatting possible in good way. The only right box is the "answer" box which helps others to find also a solution. But it is not allowed to use the answer button. I understand the "point system" does not allow it but it is unusable. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialize your `TextReader` with the appropriate encoding:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
{
    // read the text
}
```